# How to load .csv of complex numbers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a `.csv` file that has a column of data being complex. When I use `data = load(file_name)`, the imaginary parts of that column are all discarded!

How may I import them into MATLAB without losing my imaginary part?

Comment: Usually `csvread()` works decently when dealing with complex data (with some limitations). Type `doc csvread` and press [Enter] on Matlab console to see how to call the function; try it, and please come back with feedback. If it doesn't work, we can figure something out. :-)

Comment: I can confirm that `csvread()` does support complex data as I've had to use it before.  If you want to double check, go to the MATLAB documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html and look under the Algorithms heading in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `csvread()` should help you here.  It does support reading in complex data if your column data is in complex format.

Check the MATLAB documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html and look under the Algorithms heading.